# meu boolean não responde , o que devo fazer?

Tags: java, eclipse, javascript-eventos, booleano

meu codigo é

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable,KeyListener{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static JFrame frame;
private Thread thread;
private boolean isRunning = true;
private final int WIDTH = 240;
private final int HEIGHT = 160;
private final int SCALE = 3;

private BufferedImage image;

private Player player;

public List<Entity> entities;
public Spritesheet spritesheet;



public Game(){
    addKeyListener(this);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE));
    initFrame();
    //inicializando Objetos
    image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    spritesheet = new Spritesheet("/spritesheet.png");
    
    Player player = new Player(0,0,16,16,spritesheet.getSprite(32, 0, 16, 16));
    entities.add(player);
}

public void initFrame(){
    frame = new JFrame("Game");
    frame.add(this);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public synchronized void start(){
    thread = new Thread(this);
    isRunning = true;
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop(){
    
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.start();
}

public void tick() {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < entities.size(); i++) {
        Entity e = entities.get(i);
        if(e instanceof Player){
            //estou dando tick no player
        }
        e.tick();
    }
}

public void render(){
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(new Color(10,10,10));
    g.fillRect(0, 0,WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE);
    
    /*Renderização do jogo*/
    for(int i = 0 ; i < entities.size(); i++) {
        Entity e = entities.get(i);
        e.render(g);
    }

    /***/
    g.dispose();
    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image,0,0,WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE,null);
    bs.show();
}
    
public void run(){
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    double timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(isRunning){
      long now = System.nanoTime();
      delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
      lastTime = now;
      if(delta >= 1){
          tick();
          render();
          frames++;
          delta--;
      }
      if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer >= 1000){
          System.out.println("FPS:"+frames);
          frames = 0;
          timer+=1000;
      }
    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    
    
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
        player.right=true;    
    }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
        
    }
    
    
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        
    }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        
    }
    
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}
```

}

o player não responde/reconhece o right o que devo fazer?

erros:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.RedStar_Games.main.Game.keyPressed(Game.java:143)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6590)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6409)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1950)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:871)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1140)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1010)
at java.desktop/java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:836)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc tem uma variável global chamada de `player` que está nula e é essa variável que está sendo utilizada no método `keyPressed()`

```
public Game(){
    ...
    
    Player player = new Player(0,0,16,16,spritesheet.getSprite(32, 0, 16, 16));
    entities.add(player);
}
```

Na sua classe `Game` vc não está utilizando a variável global e sim criando uma nova, percebe? Para corrigir isso, uma alternativa seria simplesmente utilizar a variável global:

```
 public Game(){
    ...
    
    player = new Player(0,0,16,16,spritesheet.getSprite(32, 0, 16, 16));
    entities.add(player);
}
```